# Cannot start windows service when using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices

Tags: .net, windows-services, background-service, .net-core-3.0

I tried to follow the recommendations [here](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2019/10/15/windowsservice/) for creating a Windows service using `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices`. So far so good, everything works fine, my background service's `ExecuteAsync` gets called and the log says that everything is OK. Starting the application as a console application works fine, too, I can start it, do whatever I need to do, then stop it.

However, I try then to install the Windows service using:

`sc create myservice binPath= "\"<path-to-the-exe-file>\" service" start= auto DisplayName= "My Service"`

I get `[SC] CreateService SUCCESS`. But when I try to start the service manually, it tells me that it did not respond in timely manner. Again, the log is fine, no errors. The Event Viewer tells me nothing more about what it can go wrong and I don't have any clue what can I do next to find the cause of the problem.

Here is an approximate code I used to configure the host:

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
IContainer container = null; 

var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(appArgs);
hostBuilder
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new CustomAutofacServiceProviderFactory(() => container))
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<BackgroundWorker>();
        containerBuilder.Populate(services);
        container = containerBuilder.Build();
    })
    .UseWindowsService();
```

And this is the class I use for the background service.

```cs
public class BackgroundWorker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IAppContext appContext;
    private CancellationTokenRegistration stopRegistration;

    public BackgroundWorker(ILogger<BackgroundWorker> logger, IAppContext appContext)
    {
        this.Logger = logger;
        this.appContext = appContext;
    }

    public ILogger<BackgroundWorker> Logger { get; }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        this.Logger.Info("Background worker started.");

        this.stopRegistration = stoppingToken.Register(() =>
        {
            this.Logger.Info("Background worker stopping...");
            this.stopRegistration.Dispose();
            this.Logger.Info("Background worker stopped.");
        });

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I am curious though why you have the container external to the rest of the factory?

Comment: This is only an illustration of the container being built at the wrong time. This is not how production code should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer just now, after a couple of hours of struggling.

I am using Autofac as a Dependency Injection container and in `HostBuilder.ConfigureServices()` I was building the Autofac container.

AFTER THAT I called `.UseWindowsService()`, which was too late, as Autofac was already done with building the container.

So, the answer is, use `.UseWindowsService()` BEFORE the container is built, otherwise it will have no effect on the composed services.

Here is the changed code that is working:

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
IContainer container = null; 

var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(appArgs);
hostBuilder
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new CustomAutofacServiceProviderFactory(() => container))
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<BackgroundWorker>();
    })
    .UseWindowsService() //<-- Done BEFORE building container
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        containerBuilder.Populate(services);
        container = containerBuilder.Build();
    })
```

Comment: Just for the record, this is an illustration of the container being built at the right time. This is not how production code should look like, as @Nkosi pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally the container should not be external to the rest of the setup.

You are already using a custom service provider factory that should incorporate what you are doing manually.

Autofac already has [AutofacServiceProviderFactory](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/blob/develop/src/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/AutofacServiceProviderFactory.cs)

```
/// <summary>
/// A factory for creating a <see cref="ContainerBuilder"/> and an <see cref="IServiceProvider" />.
/// </summary>
public class AutofacServiceProviderFactory : IServiceProviderFactory<ContainerBuilder>
{
    private readonly Action<ContainerBuilder> _configurationAction;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AutofacServiceProviderFactory"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="configurationAction">Action on a <see cref="ContainerBuilder"/> that adds component registrations to the conatiner.</param>
    public AutofacServiceProviderFactory(Action<ContainerBuilder> configurationAction = null)
    {
        _configurationAction = configurationAction ?? (builder => { });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a container builder from an <see cref="IServiceCollection" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">The collection of services.</param>
    /// <returns>A container builder that can be used to create an <see cref="IServiceProvider" />.</returns>
    public ContainerBuilder CreateBuilder(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Populate(services);

        _configurationAction(builder);

        return builder;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an <see cref="IServiceProvider" /> from the container builder.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="containerBuilder">The container builder.</param>
    /// <returns>An <see cref="IServiceProvider" />.</returns>
    public IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
    {
        if (containerBuilder == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(containerBuilder));

        var container = containerBuilder.Build();

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
    }
}
```

Note how the container builder is created and populated by the factory and the service provider built from the `IContainer`

That should allow for the original setup to be done without the need to manually create the container externally

```
var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(appArgs)
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddHostedService<BackgroundWorker>();            
    });
```

Reference [Documentation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting)

Reference [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection)

Comment: You're right, my setup is more complicated than this and I do it just like you are suggesting. The thing is that during the build flow the container was built before the `WindowsService()` method had the chance to add its services to the builder. In the simplified flow I provided I wanted to make it visible that the container is built before `WindowsService()` is called.